# AppEngine URI Errors in Admin Dashboard

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have uploaded new version of Google App Engine and enable the uploaded version of the app as the default version. Im using Java. I found out in admin console that old files that are not in the new version is still requested.

Im referring in admin console dashboard, under URI errors. E.g. I have the error for `/image/main.jpg` in URI errors.

In my `appengine-web.xml` file, I have the following expiration of static files:

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/js/**" expiration="30m"/>
    <include path="/image/**" expiration="30m"/>
    <include path="/css/**" expiration="30m"/>
</static-files>
```

Why do I get URI errors for the file that is not in enabled version?

Answer (score 0):

Did you go to the admin and set the default version to be your new version?

Comment: yes. but i think returned users were served w/ d previous version or maybe problem on browser caching?